# Way to turn all images with ".jpg.webp" file extension on page into just ".jpg"?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts, webp

For work, I deal with a lot of pages that have images with .jpg.webp file extensions. This can be a pain when trying to save those images and using them on other platforms that don't accept .webp file extensions. I am trying to find a way to automatically set all the images on a specific page to just .jpg file extensions (instead of .jpg.webp).

I have separate code that turns the images into .jpg files, but only when the image is opened alone in a new tab. The URL still includes .jpg.webp as the ending file extension in the new tab, but defaults to .jpg extension when saving.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          JS
// @match         https://example.com/*
// @author        erosman
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".jpg.webp"]').forEach(item => 
    item.src = item.src.replace('.webp', ''));
```

Basically, after a page loads, I'd like to simply right-click an image (which would be a .jpg.webp in this case) and save it as a .jpg. I want the script to turn all of the .jpg.webp filetype extensions of every image on the page into just .jpg (ultimately making .jpg the default save option in the pop-up menu after the right-click, too).

I'm not quite sure how to bridge the gap between the above code and simply turning all the images on the page into just .jpg. without the .webp extension.

Any and all suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Most probably the website you work with host both jpg and webp and displays it as `<picture>` with several `<source>`, no ? Because if they only have a webp file it's not really nice for all those Safari users...

Comment: I think so. I know that at least .jpg, .png, and .webp are on the site. It's just that every filetype is attached with an additional .webp (after the .jpg or .png) at least on my Chrome browser. Since I can easily download the non .webp versions in the code I have in the original post, that would imply that the .jpg's and .png's are hosted, too. Searching with those file extensions in the URL minus the .webp also yields a downloadable image (with the original image extension).

Comment: You can add a listener for `mousedown` event on `window` and change the src if event.target is a matching image. Anyway, we might need to see an excerpt of HTML from that page to provide further help.